# Плавный скролинг по секциям на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript, анимация, прокрутка

На сайте нужно реализовать плавную прокрутку по секциям на **чистом** javascript, без всяких плагинов и библиотек.

Есть код:

```js
var height = document.querySelector("section").clientHeight;

(function() {
  var supportOffset = window.pageYOffset !== undefined,
    lastKnownPos = 0,
    ticking = false,
    scrollDir;

  function doSomething(scrollPos, scrollDir) {
    if (scrollDir === 'down') {
      window.scrollBy(0, height);
    }
    console.log('scroll pos: ' + scrollPos + ' | scroll dir: ' + scrollDir);
  }

  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    currYPos = supportOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;
    scrollDir = lastKnownPos > currYPos ? 'up' : 'down';
    lastKnownPos = currYPos;

    if (!ticking) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        doSomething(lastKnownPos, scrollDir);
        ticking = false;
      });
    }
    ticking = true;
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  width: 33.1605%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
  <section></section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Как видно, прокрутка работает криво, не пойми как, хотелось бы, чтобы она была плавная и по секциям, никак не получается додумать скрипт. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 6):

Краткость - сестра таланта)))

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.deltaY < 0) scrollToSection('first');
  else scrollToSection('second');
});

function scrollToSection(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  width: 33.1605%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <section id="first">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="second"></section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

А это для секций, которых > 2

```js
const sections = [...document.getElementsByTagName('section')];
let currentSection = 0;

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  (e.deltaY < 0) ? --currentSection: ++currentSection;

  if (currentSection < 0) currentSection = 0;
  else if (currentSection > (sections.length - 1)) currentSection = (sections.length - 1);

  scrollToSection(currentSection);
});

function scrollToSection(i) {
  document.getElementById(sections[i].id).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  width: 33.1605%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <section id="first">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="second"></section>
  <section id="third"></section>
  <section id="fourth"></section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: А если таких секций будет 5, 10 штук?)

Comment: Дополнил код. Массив секций формируется автоматом. P.S. Если ответ норм, поставь +1 плз)